# React - On button click displaying another form but form rendering behind other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

As of now when the user presses the ADD button, my code creates a subcategory (a new form). They can press the ADD button as many times as they'd like and it appends a new form onto the UI. My problems is that these new forms are rendering behind the other categories (as shown in the picture, that is what it looks like after I press the ADD button for "Discount Department Stores").

UI after ADD button pressed

[image: UI after ADD button pressed]

How can I continue rendering the new forms while pushing the other categories down each time I render a new form?

Here is the code for the parent category AKA the code containing the ADD button.

```
const dataForms = categoriesSelected ? (
    [...categoriesMap.keys()].map((d,idx) => {
      return (
        <div key={d}>
          {d === 0 && (
            <h2 className="text-center mb-3" id="header">
              Input Data For Selected Categories
            </h2>
          )}
          <div key={d} className="input-data-select-container mb-4 children">
            <Row>
              <Col xs="10">
                <h3 className="font-weight-light">{d}</h3>
              </Col>
              <Col xs="2">
                  <Button className="addition-child"
                  onClick={(e) => addition(d)}
                >
                  Add
                </Button>

              </Col>
              </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col xs="4">
                <Label>Recommended Size:</Label>
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  min="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  name="recommendedSize"
                  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, d)}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col xs="4">
                <Label>
                  First-Year {new Date().getFullYear()} Sales Per Sq Ft:
                </Label>
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  min="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  name="firstYearSalesPerSqFt"
                  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, d)}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col xs="4">
                <Label>
                  Fifth-Year {new Date().getFullYear() + 5} Sales Per Sq Ft:
                </Label>
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  min="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  name="fifthYearSalesPerSqFt"
                  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, d)}
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <FormGroup className="mt-2">
              <Label>Select Recommended Vendors:</Label>
              <Select
                closeMenuOnSelect={true}
                options={orderedSuggestedRetailers[idx]}
                isMulti
                // options={apparelAndAccessories}
                placeholder="Select all the recommended vendors for the report. "
                maxMenuHeight="270px"
                onChange={(e) => addRetailer(e, d)}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <div className="children">
            {children(d, idx)}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })) : (
    <h2 className="text-center">No Categories Selected</h2>
  );
```

Note in that code I am displaying the children with this line in that code:

```
{children(d, idx)}
```

This is the code that makes the child subcategories:

```
function children(d, idx) {
    let output = [];
    for(let i = 0; i <= categoriesMap.get(d).amount-2; i++) {
      const temp = (
        <div key={i} className="input-data-select-container">
          <Label>{d}</Label>
          <Row>
              <Col xs="4">
                <Label>Recommended Size:</Label>
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  min="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  name="recommendedSize"
                  onChange={(e) => handleInputChangeOfChild(e, d, i+1)}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col xs="4">
                <Label>
                  First-Year {new Date().getFullYear()} Sales Per Sq Ft:
                </Label>
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  min="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  name="firstYearSalesPerSqFt"
                  onChange={(e) => handleInputChangeOfChild(e, d, i+1)}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col xs="4">
                <Label>
                  Fifth-Year {new Date().getFullYear() + 5} Sales Per Sq Ft:
                </Label>
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  min="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  name="fifthYearSalesPerSqFt"
                  onChange={(e) => handleInputChangeOfChild(e, d, i+1)}
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <FormGroup className="mt-2">
              <Label>Select Recommended Vendors:</Label>
              <Select
                closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                options={orderedSuggestedRetailers[idx]}
               // options={apparelAndAccessories}
                isMulti
                placeholder="Select all the recommended vendors for the report. "
                maxMenuHeight="270px"
                onChange={(e) => addRetailerOfChild(e, d, i+1)}
              />
            </FormGroup>
        </div>
      );
      output[i] = (temp);
    }
    return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see the CSS of your code. For me, it seems that some parent div is with a **fixed height**, so its children is being rendered outside of it!

If that's the case, you can fix it by using `min-height` and `max-height` to set a dynamic height in CSS.